# validate a textbox value for the current date in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have a calendar control whose value will be displayed in a textbox, i need to validate the textbox value to the current date... It should not be less than current date.....

Thanks for ur valuable reply for my last post

Comment: don't forget to accept answers for previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CompareValidator` control, like this:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="dateValidator" 
                      ControlToValidate="IdOfTextBox"
                      Text="error message"
                      Operator="GreaterThanEqual"
                      Type="Date"
                      runat="server" />
```

And in the code-behind, set the `ValueToCompare` property of the validator to `DateTime.Today` (for example in the `Page_Init` method).

Comment: but it says '31/03/2005' is greater then today

Answer (score 0):

Try This in Code Behind :

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Date Should be Greater Than Current Date"
ControlToValidate="txt_DateFrom"  ValuetoCompare='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString("d") %>' SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Use CompareValidator control, set properties as below: 
operator = GreaterThanEqual
Type = Date
ValueToCompare = CurrentDate